In STM32F4 Complementary PWM, Can we set %0 dutycycle both CH1 and CH1N
My question is about complementary PWM. Can we get %0 dutycycle at CH1 and CH1N at the same time. Datasheet of MCU: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0383-stm32f411xce-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf




Please link the data sheet for the chip and explain on which page CH1 and CH1N are described.


This code looks like works. I will give feedback in the power electronics circuit behaivour of this code.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Depends what do you mean by "0% duty cycle". Usualy complementary outputs means that one output is inverted copy of second output (forgot dead time for now). And when one output is at 0% PWM (permanently in Low level), second output is permenently in High level ... and we call that "0% PWM". But probably this is not case you are asking.
If you asking if it is possible to have CH1 and CH1N both in the same state (for example both in Low level), then yes. You can select polarity for each timer output, CH1N can also be pure copy of CH1. Moreover you can also change GPIO mode from "alternate function" to "Output" and tie it Low manualy (regardless what is timer output).

I can implement this via given table at manual reference. I am now trying more complex control with able to set low one of the CH1 or CH2 while one of them giving PWM.
